# Як перекласти genesis block?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Маємо таке пояснення словосполуки:

> A **genesis block** is the first block of a block chain. Modern versions
>   of Bitcoin number it as block 0, though very early versions counted it
>   as block 1. The genesis block is almost always hardcoded into the
>   software of the applications that utilize its block chain. It is a
>   special case in that it does not reference a previous block, and for
>   Bitcoin and almost all of its derivatives, it produces an unspendable
>   subsidy.

[Bitcoinwiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block)

Цілком розумно лишити блок, а от як бути з генезисом?

Варіанти словникового перекладу **genesis** - генезис, буття, походження.

Як пристосувати ці переклади до слова **блок**? Чи правильним буде варіант **першоблок**?

Answer (score 3):

> [**genesis**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/genesis) - the origin of something, when it is begun or starts to exist
>
> the time when something came into existence; the beginning or origin:

*Те походження чогось, коли воно починається чи починає існувати.*

*Той час, коли щось виникло; початок або походження.*

> **[Зародження](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)** - Дія за знач. зароди́ти і зароди́тися.
>
> ЗАРОДИ́ТИ - Див. заро́джувати.
>
> ЗАРО́ДЖУВАТИ - Давати початок чиєму-небудь існуванню, життю;
>   породжувати.

Тобто маємо:

> Блок зародження - це перший блок ланцюга блоків. Сучасні версії
>   Bitcoin називають його блоком 0, хоча дуже ранні версії зараховують
>   його до блоку 1. Блок зародження майже завжди жорстко кодується до
>   програмного забезпечення додатків, що використовують його блок-ланцюг.
>   Це особливий випадок, коли він не посилається на попередній блок, а
>   для Bitcoin та майже всіх його похідних він отримує невиплачену
>   субсидію.

Answer (score 2):

Я схильний називати його **генезис блок**. Термінологія в блокчейн технологіях повинна бути співзвучна з оригінальною, інакше вас ніхто не буде розуміти.
Для більш чіткішого пояснення можна використовувати словосполучення **початковий блок**.

Comment: Думав поставити -1, але з другою частиною відповіді я згоден. Тому +1 -1. Не згоден щодо "Термінологія в блокчейн технологіях повинна бути співзвучна з оригінальною".